# Share the internet connection of the master node with a slave node.

Tags: perl, cluster-computing

I'm working on a node of a cluster and I have to install several perl module. I would do that through cpan but I can't do that because I don't have any access to internet from that node. However I have full access to the master node where a connection is available.
How can I use the connection of the master node to use cpan on the slave node. 
Are there other solutions?
I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend this module: [CPAN::Mini](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/CPAN-Mini-1.111013/lib/CPAN/Mini.pm).

This module make easy the creation of a **mirror of CPAN locally**. Then, configure your mirror URL in CPAN to the local directory using a URL like this:

```
file:///my/local/cpan/mirror
```